# Gnome-shell wayland, rotate screen

Tags: multiple-monitors, gnome-shell, wayland

Assuming I'm using intel's driver.

Gnome-shell allows to rotate screens in Settings -> Display when using Xorg.

Is it possible to rotate when using Wayland?

Comment: Ha, just upgraded to 3.18 on Arch and ran into the same issue... haven't seen it addressed anywhere else.

Comment: @aiguofer, I use Xorg and gnome-shell 3.18 in Arch too, but there is a bug when using two monitors and one is rotated (CCW in my case) the pointer has an offset, so when I try to focus a button for example it doesn't really get focus, unless I move the cursor to the left until I get focus to the desired element. Very annoying. Are you experiencing this too?
That's why I'm trying to use wayland, but it doesn't rotate monitors.

Comment: oh that's interesting, unfortunately no I don't have that bug. I'm on the intel driver on a sandy bridge machine with a hdmi monitor in horizontal mode and a vga monitor on vertical and works flawlessly on X. I tried Wayland and everything seems fine except for not being able to rotate the vertical monitor.

Answer (score 2):

I had the problem with no screen rotation buttons in the monitor settings in my Lenovo Yoga 910 laptop, which is a convertible.

After Gnome started to randomly flip the screen I disabled automatic screen rotation via:
`gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.orientation active false`

and suddenly, I've got these buttons!

Answer (score 1):

GNOME's Mutter supports screen rotation on Wayland since 3.20, and 3.22 has improved it.
   https://wiki.gnome.org/ThreePointTwentyone/ReleaseNotes

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution is to set the `rotate-monitor` key to some keybinding using `gsettings` or `dconf-editor`.

For instance, the following command will cause `Ctrl+F8` to rotate the screen counterclockwise:

```
$ gsettings set org.gnome.mutter.keybindings rotate-monitor "['XF86RotateWindows', '<Control>F8']"
```

This does not allow the user to specify the target orientation, but only to rotate the screen until the desired orientation is reached.

(original posted here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/465395/20661)